# cglib jars always give errors with different versions when start Tomcat 9.0.13

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, cglib

I deployed a web application to the Tomcat 9.0.13 server, under the WEB-INF/lib there are Hibernate related jar files. When I start the server, it give me errors in many Hibernate mapping classes:

```
1991 [main] ERROR proxy.BasicLazyInitializer  - CGLIB Enhancement failed: com.usps.nom.tops.model.impl.ComputedHardCloseoutImpl
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
        at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:41)
```

The original Cglib version is cglib-2.1.jar, and I try the latest cglib-3.2.12.jar, the original error is gone but a new error show up:

```
1619 [main] ERROR proxy.BasicLazyInitializer  - CGLIB Enhancement failed: com.usps.nom.tops.model.transportation.AplDispatch
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator
        at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:41)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:161)
```

I have tried different versions of Cglib jars file:

cglib-2.1.jar, cglib-2.1_3.jar, cglib-3.2.1.jar, cglib-3.2.12.jar, cglib-nodep-2.1.jar, cglib-nodep-3.2.12.jar

But they always give me one of the above errors.

The other Hibernate related jars under WEB-INF/lib are:
ehcache-1.1.jar, ehcache-core-2.4.8.jar,  hibernate3.jar(3.1.0)

If I start the Tomcat server locally in my Eclipse project , there is no such errors. Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are wildly trying to install random versions of a handull of libraries. Any idea what the *proper versions* are for your product? Most Java web applications these days are built with Maven and handle their own dependency-resolution. What are you doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

We inherited this web application from previous vendor IBM. It was not built with Maven. The version of hibernate related jars are:
cglib-2.1.jar, ehcache-1.1.jar, hibernate3.jar(3.1.0)

This web application was deployed to WebSphere server and it works fine so far, but now our client need to switch to Tomcat server.  The web application works okay in my local Tomcat 9.0.13 server in eclipse, but when I deploy it to our web server, those errors occur when I start the server. Thanks.